# How to toggle rich:accordion

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, accordion

I use a rich:accordion to display information in two separate accordions. I have two requirements which I'm failing to implement :

1. Collapse both accordionItems when the page loads for the first time - The default behaviour is that, the first accordionItem is expanded when the page loads. I want both the accordionItems to be collapsed and should expand based on which accordion is clicked.
2. On clicking an expanded accordionItem, it should be collapsed - Once I click on an accordionItem which is collapsed, it expands and shows the information it contains. But if I click on it again, nothing happens. I want to collapse the accordionItem on clicking on it again (when it is already expanded).

I use richfaces 4.0 and jsf 2

Answer (score 0):

Accordion is meant to behave that way (i.e. one panel is always open), if you want a component  that opens/closes on click you can use `<rich:collapsiblePanel>`. Of course, opening one will not close the other but if you need that functionality it's not hard to add it to the two panels.